# Adding additional properties to a Chart JS dataset

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, canvas, chart.js

I'm trying to add extra properties to a Chart JS dataset (for a Pie / Doughnut chart). I've got a piece of Ruby on the back-end that prints the following JSON to the view:

```
[
{"segment": "undetermined",
"label": "Undetermined",
"value": 420193," 
color": "#DECF3F",
"highlight": "#e2d455"
},
{"segment":"peer_review",
"label":"Peer Review",
"value":415212,
"color":"#60BD68",
"highlight":"#72c479"
}
]
```

The "segment" property is an additional one (not provided for by the library) that I want to make available to my JS on the front-end. However when I wrap this JSON in a `canvas` tag I can't access it through JS.

The second line below outputs the above JSON:

```
<canvas id="review-type" height="235" data-facet="review_status_s">
  <%= @by_review_type %> 
</canvas>
```

And I'm trying to access the "segment" property by using the `getSegmentsAtEvent()` API call (name collision accidental):

```
   $("#review-type").click(
    function(evt) {
      var activePoints = reviewChart.getSegmentsAtEvent(evt);

      /* extract other properties, then build an URL from them: */

      var url = "/" +locale+ "/catalog?f[" +facet_frag+ "][]=" +segment+ "&q=*:*";
      window.location = url;
    }
  );
```

However when I inspect `activePoints` in the JS console, "segment" isn't on the list of properties.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

`getSegmentsAtEvent` (and its equivalents for other chart types) return chart elements (sectors, points, bars, etc.). You have to use any of the chart element properties and the data object to figure out the index and then use that to get the additional property that you want.

For instance, if `pieData` is your data object

```
$("#review-type").click(
    function (evt) {
        var activePoints = reviewChart.getSegmentsAtEvent(evt);

        if (activePoints.length)
        alert(pieData.filter(function (e) { return e.label === activePoints[0].label; })[0].segment);
            ...
```

You could also set additional properties on the properties that get transferred from the object to the element (e.g. `label`), but that's a bit hacky.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nm9ay728/